# returning to a loop when it doesn't meet a certain condition

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop

So I have a while loop that calculates the value of a variable for me.
If that variable does not reach the condition that I want to, is it possible to return to the while loop and insert new variables, and keep returning to the loop until I get the condition that i want.

```
balance=3329
annualInterestRate=0.2/12
month=0
min_pay=10

while month<12:
    new_bal=balance+(balance*annualInterestRate)-min_pay
    balance=new_bal
    month=month+1

if balance>0:
    min_pay+=10
```

So if by the end of the loop the balance>0 then I want to add 10 to min_pay and go through the loop with the original values. And I want it to keep going until balance<=0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a nested while loop:

```
min_pay=10
while True:
    balance=3329
    annualInterestRate=0.2/12
    month=0

    while month<12:
        new_bal=balance+(balance*annualInterestRate)-min_pay
        balance=new_bal
        month=month+1

    if balance>0:
        min_pay+=10
    else:
        break
```